# Port 9000 Open in FW But Not Showing In NMAP

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, traceroute, viewports

I am running an Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS virtual server.
I need to be able to access http://localhost:9000/ from within the server for a service I am trying to run, but I keep getting 'Connection refused' errors.

I have tried running telnet to this port and got the following message:

```
$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I know that telnet is working since I've successfully logges in via different ports (the ones shown on the nmap results below).

Checking the FW and iptables, the port seems like it should be open:

iptables:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:mysql
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:9000
```

FW:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3306                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # accept Apache
9000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9000/udp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # accept Apache
9000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9000/udp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

When I run nmap, I don't see the port as open:

```
$ nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-08-09 11:04 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000073s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Attached is my traceroute log:

```
$ sudo tcptraceroute localhost 9000
Running:
        traceroute -T -O info -p 9000 localhost
traceroute to localhost (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1) <rst,ack>  0.017 ms  0.005 ms  0.004 ms
```

**EDIT:**

netstat results:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      818/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      900/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      978/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      947/redis-server 12
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      900/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2401/apache2
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6379                :::*                    LISTEN      947/redis-server 12
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2401/apache2
```

**It seems that I don't have any service listening on port 9000. How can this be fixed?**

Could anyone please help me diagnose the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any service that you expect listens to port 9000 ?

Comment: I should have Taxii listening on that port, but even so, why can't I telnet to it?

Comment: All output you posted looks like it's simply no service listening on port 9000. Check with `netstat`.

Comment: Please see edit. Turns out do I not have any service listening on port 9000. How can I fix this, at least for telnet purposes so that I can further diagnose the issue?

Comment: I guess that you have to install, configure and start the relevant service, taxi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the gunicorn server I had running got shut down every time I exited its CLI. I solved this by using a daemon to make its processes run in the background.

```
(venv) $ gunicorn opentaxii.http:app \
>   --bind localhost:9000 --config python:opentaxii.http --daemon
```